# cellForRowAtIndexPath is in model or view?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, model

I would like to be conform with pattern MVC and i ask me, where the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method must to go :/
Because, at the moment, this method is in the Controller File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking whether it should be in the Model (M) or Controller (C), I assume.  And it's an interesting question, because UITableView has two protocols:

```
UITableViewDelegate
UITableViewDataSource
```

Well, the UITableViewDelegate protocol is for the 'owner' of the view, which would be generally the Controller - I haven't seen any code that assumes otherwise.

So then where should the UITableViewDataSource sit? This is the protocol that defines

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Now, if the Apple developers assumed it would go in the Controller, why not just incorporate it into the UITableViewDelegate protocol? The documentation says this (with my bold):

> The UITableViewDataSource protocol is **adopted by an object that
>   mediates the application’s data model for a UITableView object**. The
>   data source provides the table-view object with the information it
>   needs to construct and modify a table view.
>
> As a representative of the data model, the data source supplies
>   minimal information about the table view’s appearance. The table-view
>   object’s delegate—an object adopting the UITableViewDelegate
>   protocol—provides that information.

So that seems to suggest it should sit in the model - but really by saying "mediates the application's data model" it means it should sit in a Controller - but perhaps not the same controller that actually manages the `UITableView` (via the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol).   It seems to me you have the flexibility to look at laying this out in a couple of different ways - however the general conclusion is that in 99% of the code I've seen it sits in the Controller which also is also the `UITableViewDelegate` delegate.

Here's some Apple documentation on MVC: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14-SW9

Answer (score 0):

The goal of a controller object (the C in MVC) is to coordinate model objects with view objects. Thus, the nature of the method cellForRowAtIndexPath, which populates a given cell (which is a view) with data (which comes from a model) dictates that it belongs in a controller.

This approach is demonstrated in all of Apple's sample code pertaining to UITableViews and UITableViewControllers.